# Android: MediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd) vs MediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I have created 3 Asset file descriptor of 3 sounds (put in res/raw)

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd1 = mContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.mp3_file_1);

AssetFileDescriptor afd2 = mContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.mp3_file_2);

AssetFileDescriptor afd3 = mContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.mp3_file_3);
```

Then I put them into an array:

```
    array.add(afd1);
    array.add(afd2);
    array.add(afd3);
```

Then I create an instance of MediaPlayer and let it play only the first sound in the array

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(array.get(0).getFileDescriptor());
mp.prepare();
mp.start()
```

However, all the 3 sounds in the array are played.
Then I tried to use setDataSource(FileDescriptor, long, long) instead of  setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd), the mp plays ONLY the 1st sound in the array as I wanted.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = array.get(0);

mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
```

My question is what is the difference between the TWO setDataSource methods above? With the code I included here, why setDataSource(array.get(0)) plays all 3 sounds in the array?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is told length (and offset) while the first one plays as long as the file descriptor returns some data. Resources are usually stored in an archive so reading from the file descriptor continues past the first song where it finds the second song and then the third song.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. However, I still vaguely understand the concept of file descriptor. If using file descriptor without setting length and offset will make the MediaPlayer plays from FileDecriptor_1 to FileDecriptor_2, FileDecriptor_3, and so on. So what is the use of the method setDataResource(FileDescriptor fd) then? I assume that there should have only setDataSource(FileDescriptor, long startOffset, long length). This is what I still don't understand.

Comment: File decriptor points inside the whole file so you need to provide offset and length for resources because all resources are in one big archive (file). If you open a file in your application data directory or on SD card, there is no  content other than the file and you don't need to specify offset and length.

Comment: Thank you a lot StenSoft! I am newbie in android programming so I really need help from kind people like you! Have a nice day!